# Decal Machine Decal import

Tags: add-on

How do I import decal packs? I have put some extra decals into the "My Decals" folder. None of them load. I am using 2.81a. I am running Win 10 64bit if this makes any difference.

Answer (score 2):

What you needed here was to hit the little refresh arrows next to the library names in the add-on preferences.

For future reference there is a Discord channel for support.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that your decals are installed in the right directory.

[image]

[image]

After that, restart blender and they should appear.