# How do I import 3rd party decal packs into decalMACHINE?

Tags: import

Man this is frustrating. I've spent an entire day on this and wound up nowhere. I purchased some decal packs at blender market, but I can't figure out how to import them into decal machine. I read the answer to Decal Machine Decal import, but that was no help whatsoever. For one thing there is no "refresh" button in decalMachine's prefs. There's a "reload button" but that didn't do anything either. And although the person asking the question at least seemed to know what folder to copy things to, I'm just too dumb to know that. And sentences like "Accept. Open a file browser, Hold Shift to open the file, Alt to browse  containing directory" that pops up in decal machine's prefs when you hover over the import file button mean nothing to me. "Hold Shift to open the file"? WHAT file? Pack_2_png.zip? PSD.zip? Letters.zip? Which file? And what's this about "Alt to browse containing directory"? What does that even mean? Could someone please pretend you're talking to a four year old and tell me, step by step, how to preform the import once I'm in decalMACHINE's prefs (I at least know how to get to the prefs). But do NOT skip steps or assume I can understand terms that someone new to Blender might not understand. I would be eternally, and sincerely grateful. I'm using decalMACHINE 1.9.4

Answer (score 1):

The folder that was referred in [that question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/164534/decal-machine-decal-import) is the DecalMachine assets folder, which by default is on `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\[version]\scripts\addons\DECALmachine\assets\Decals\`, or the one you've set under Assets on DecalMachine's preferences.

The folders with "uuid" files are your decals. You can either drop them to the "MyDecals" folder or make a separate folder under the path above.

It also took me a while to find this. Hope this helps!